# How to perform feature scaling in this regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I was learning from a Python ML course. I got a warning saying something is wrong with my code. This is my code:

```
# SVR(Support Vector Regression)

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
X = sc_X.transform(X)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))

# Fitting the Regression Model to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict([[6.5]])

# Visualising the SVR results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

# Visualising the Regression results (for higher resolution and smoother curve)
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid, regressor.predict(X_grid), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Regression Model)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Here is the warning:

```
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:724: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py:193: FutureWarning: The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.
  "avoid this warning.", FutureWarning)
```

I think there is an option to turn Feature Scaling to auto. If there isn't, the code for Feature Scaling would really help.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
 regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma='auto')
```

Check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) for full parameter list